# Counting total occurences and occurences by category based on date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In the table below, the Start and End dates represent a period of time in which a unique identifyer is counted. My goal is count the number of times the unique identifyer falls between the date, but show it on a monthly basis. I'd also like to count the number of times that a category falls in that date range.

I'm new at working with table data and pandas so I'm a bit lost. Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Example input data:

| Start Date | End Date | Unique Identifyer | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-04-17 | 2020-04-17 | ID 1234 | A |
| 2019-05-20 | 2021-04-03 | ID 3492 | B |
| 2019-05-20 | 2021-04-03 | ID 7376 | C |
| 2019-04-18 | 2021-04-03 | ID 9813 | A |
| 2019-06-20 | 2021-04-03 | ID 6342 | A |
| 2019-06-20 | 2021-04-03 | ID 6455 | B |
| 2019-07-20 | 2021-04-03 | ID 6342 | A |
| 2019-06-20 | 2021-04-03 | ID 6455 | B |
| etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... |

example of output:

| Date | Total_Vol | count_A | count_B | count_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apr-2019 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| May-2019 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Jun-2019 | 7 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| Jul-2019 | 8 | 4 | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i'd recommend to split the date column in two distincts columns `year` and `month` so that you can group by them.

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['start', 'end', 'id', 'cat'])
         .astype({'start':'datetime64', 'end':'datetime64'})
         .assign(year=lambda x: x['start'].dt.year)
         .assign(month=lambda x: x['start'].dt.month))
```

[image]

Then you can explode the `cat` column to facilitate the computation

```
df_cats = (pd
 .get_dummies(df['cat'], prefix='count')
 .assign(total = lambda r: r['count_A']+r['count_B']+r['count_C']))
```

You'll get

[image]

Now you just have to merge both dfs and to use `groupby.sum()` to get the result

```
pd.merge(df, df_cats, left_index=True, right_index=True).groupby(['year', 'month'].sum()
```

You'll end up with

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, this is really helpful. Appreciate your time. Although this is really close to what I'm looking for, I don't think I was clear in my original question for part of it. I got the correct output from following your code, however there's a modification that I need. I need to count the categories (and the total sum of categories) for every year/month when the categories (and total sum of categories) occur between the start and end dates, rather than just the start date. So in effect, it would be counting the same category from start date, and keep counting until it reaches end date

Comment: Perhaps timedelta from datetime would help with this?

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that point ... Not sure if it would be the most efficient solution but you could imagine to replace your start/end columns with a single one that would take the value of every month within start and end. You'll get one new row for each month within the range you're interested in